# Receiving a HTTP call on a Rasbperry PI from the Internet

Tags: python, http, raspberry-pi

I am desperatly trying to receive a HTTP call in RPI Python code.

My RPI is listening for HTTP on port 1234. I can succesfully hit this from another computer (on the same local network) by putting http://192.168.0.100:1234 (this is the PI's IP).

But if I try http://192.168.0.1:1234 then I get Connection Refused.

I have jumped through all kinds of hoops like setting up forwarding of port 1234 and I have even put 192.168.0.100 in DMZ on the router. Still I get Connection Refused.

I have tried this on 3 different kinds of routers to no avail. These routers are the kind where you have a WAN port.

Also I have tried to hit port 1234 from the Internet and that is still the same. I suppose that if this does not work locally then there is no hope of getting it to work from the Internet.

I am told that by default the RPI is not behind any kind of firewall so there for I strongly suspect the router.

Help me StackOverflow, you're my only hope:-)

Kind regards Martin

Comment: Does your router have public IP address on WAN (Internet) interface? You should be able to see that address somewhere in router administration interface. Compare address shown as assigned to WAN interface there with address reported by e.g. http://www.whatsmyip.org/ . If these are same it means at least your router is accessible from Internet. Then you'll probably need setup some port-forwarding rule to pass connection to RPi.

Comment: That's confirmed! But as stated above I have tried all kinds of port-forwarding.

Comment: As @blami mentioned, you must make the request to your router's *public* IP. http://192.168.0.1:1234 is *internal* to your network. Use the your public IP (provided by http://www.whatsmyip.org/) and see if the connection is routed to your pi. E.g. http://your.public.IP.address:1234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys. I must have shot myself in the leg at some point. I am quite sure that I verified publicaddress:1234 at some point. But now it works so I am happy.
Kind regards Martin